# Convert "hour:minute" character column to numeric column of minutes (column has NA values)

Tags: r, datetime, na

I have a character column called ipaq_2 in r that is like "02:00" (hour:minute). Also the column has some NA values. I need to convert this column into a numeric column that shows the minutes (in the above example: 120), replacing at the same time NA values with the mean.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the character column to hours and minutes with `lubridate::hm`, then convert the value to minutes. Then, we can replace any `NA` values with the mean of the minutes column.

```
library(lubridate)
df <- data.frame(ipaq_2 = c("1:00", "0:45", "0:30", "1:30", NA))

df$ipaq_2 <- hm(df$ipaq_2, quiet = TRUE)        # format to 'hours:minutes:seconds'

df$minutes <- hour(df$ipaq_2)*60 + minute(df$ipaq_2)

df$minutes[is.na(df$minutes)] <- mean(df$minutes, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Or another possibility (thanks to @Ben):

```
df$minutes <- as.numeric(hm(df$ipaq_2, quiet = T))/60
df$minutes[is.na(df$minutes)] <- mean(df$minutes, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Or with `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(ipaq_2 = hm(ipaq_2, quiet = TRUE),
         minutes = hour(ipaq_2)*60 + minute(ipaq_2),
         minutes = ifelse(is.na(minutes), mean(minutes, na.rm = TRUE), minutes))

# Or using the alternative above:
# df %>%
#   mutate(minutes = as.numeric(hm(ipaq_2, quiet = T))/60,
#          minutes = ifelse(is.na(minutes), mean(minutes, na.rm = TRUE), minutes))
```

**Output**

```
     ipaq_2 minutes
1  1H 0M 0S   60.00
2    45M 0S   45.00
3    30M 0S   30.00
4 1H 30M 0S   90.00
5      <NA>   56.25
```

Comment: Also consider `as.numeric(hm(df$ipaq_2, quiet = T))/60`?

Comment: @Ben Thanks, good to know! I added that in as an option; definitely cuts out some code.